# Convert first letter of each word in a string to Uppercase in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I can write this code in a simpler way but I want to write it as a function based code. I am looking to change the starting letter of each word in a string to uppercase.Please help!!

```
  function convertuc(str) {

  let arr = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");

  for (let s of arr){
  let arr2 = arr.map(s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1)).join(" ");
   }
  return arr2
  };

  console.log(convertuc("convert the first letter to upper case")); // Test//
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

You're almost there. You don't need a for loop since you're already using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (which does the iteration for you and builds a new array by transforming each string in `arr` to a new one based on the function provided).

```js
function convertuc(str) {
  let arr = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  let arr2 = arr.map(s => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1)).join(" ");
  return arr2; // note that arr2 is a string now because of .join(" ")
};

console.log(convertuc("convert the first letter to upper case"));
```

Comment: ok, thank,  all I need was to get rid of the second function and define s as (s=>).

Answer (score 4):

What about to use pure CSS?

```css
p {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<p>this is a simple sentence.</p>
```